# Asus laptop random shutdowns - not overheating, strange fan behaviour

Tags: laptop, shutdown, asus-laptop

I have ASUS N56VV for about 1½ years. In last weeks it starts randomly shutting down.

I normally work on computer when suddenly fan turn to full speed for about three seconds and then computer shutdown. It happend randomly sometimes after few days of working perfectly sometimes after 10 minutes.

First I think it is overheating but it is not.

- I cleaned all I can with compressed air. I clearly feels air going freely out from laptop.
- It happended few minutes after start in morning after full nigh off in cold room.
- It happened when I look on temperature monitor and temeprature of CPu and GPU was around 50°C.
- And it does not happened during stress test of CPU or GPU.

I tried to test what I could. CPU test passed. Memory test passed. Hard drive SMART values are good. It happened when plugged in, happened when running on battery and happened when plugged in with removed battery.

One strange thing what I observed was that after this random shutdown fan sometimes behaves strange. Sometimes it go full speed until I reset computer. Sometimes it switch between full speed and slow speed every few seconds for about a minute.

Hwinfo report here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwH2_0M5YtGsVjcxQ29oODlTZ2s/view
Hwinfo sensors log here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwH2_0M5YtGsVmctZ1lxZmc3bjA/view

Any ideas?

Comment: When the fan noise occurs, is your CPU maxed out?

Comment: No CPU is usually on low usage. Sometimes it happens eveed when no app was running and CPU was almost idle.

Comment: I assume the event logs don't show anything?

Comment: No, nothing in event log. Just common runtime messages and then boot message with "provious shutdown was unexpected".

Comment: What operating system are you using? Did you try system restore? What happens if you use another operating system? If you are on windows, does the event viewer give any useful info?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 now. Before it was Windows 10. But it happened when I booted Linux Live CD too. In event log is no information.

Comment: I hope I solved it. I completly dissassemble whole laptop, completly clean it, assemble back and no incident since then (two weeks now). So it probably was just some bad connection.